# I'm facing an issue with control structures

Tags: java

My problem is with output of my code. When I enter 20, the output must be **weird**, but I am getting **not weird**. Same with the value 18.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class conditional {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt(); 
        String ans = "";
        if(n%2 == 1){
            ans = "Weird";
        } else {
            if(n <= 2 && n >= 5){
                ans="Not weird";
            } else if(n <= 6 && n >= 20){
                ans = "Weird";
            } else{
                ans = "Not Weird";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the output must be weird,but i am getting not weird

Because, `if(n%2 == 1)` return `false` and fall to `else` block where

```
if(n <= 2 && n >= 5) is `false`
```

and

```
else if(n <= 6 && n >= 20) is also `false`
```

So, again falls to `else` block. You probably change

```
if(n <= 2 && n >= 5)
```

to

```
if(n >= 2 && n <= 5)
```

and

```
else if(n <= 6 && n >= 20)
```

to

```
else if(n >= 6 && n <= 20)
```

Otherwise, they will never be `true` and always falls to `else`.

Comment: @MattClark yes, and my intent was same to explain. :-)

Comment: Thank q for the help

Answer (score 0):

In your program last `else` is being executed. Change `&&` (logical **AND**) to `||` (logical **OR**) which will check if number is less than something `OR` higher than something, instead of checking if something is less or equal 5 `AND` higher or equal to 20 in the same time as it doesn't have a possibility to evaluate in any case.

Comment: sir,i am still getting Not weird as output for value 20 after changing logical AND to logical OR

Comment: @jatinkumar Yeah, you need to think a bit of logic of numbers you put to all of these if-else, but for sure you didn&#39;t want to check if something is less than or equal to 5 and equal to or higher than 20 in the same time, maybe you should change <= to >= and vice versa, but I might only be guessing what you were thinking of. I think Ravi's answer might be helpful in your case too.

Comment: @jatinkumar Glad that I could help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have come up with two solutions and also i see a flaw:

1. if(n%2 == 1) this code can be altered to if(n%2 == 0)
2. The flaw is **(n <= 2 && n >= 5)** . No number can be <2 and >5 at the same time. Try changing that to (n <= 2 || n >= 5) and same goes for (n <= 6 && n >= 20)



import java.util.Scanner;

public class conditional {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt(); 
        String ans = "";
        if(n%2 == 1){
            ans = "Weird";
        } else {
            if(n <= 6 || n >= 20){
                ans="Not weird";
            } else if(n <= 2 || n >= 5){
                ans = "Weird";
            } else{
                ans = "Not Weird";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir,i am still getting Not weird as output for value 20 after changing logical AND to logical OR

Comment: Hi @jatinkumar, edited my post accordingly. You have to place (n <= 6 || n >= 20) at the top logically. Also, why the code is (n%2 == 1), it has to be n%2 == 0 if you are trying to identify even numbers/ the numbers divisible by 2

Comment: Hi @jatinkumar, Please mark my post as useful if you find it useful. It would help others as well. Also, it would be an acknowledgement to me. Thanks.